# What is the difference Between Stored Procedure and Function in pgAdmin III

Tags: stored-procedures, pgadmin

Is a Function node in pgAdmin III is like a Stored Procedure?

I want to write a Stored Procedure in pgAdmin which is connected to Heroku Postgre database server. Can I do this using a by function?